# Sort a map of objects indescending order

Tags: kotlin

In Kotlin, I have a map of objects. The key is a string and the object stored with the key is an object. I want to sort the map in descending order by a property in the object. In this example, I want to sort by timestamp:

```kotlin
data class Image(val timestamp: Long)

val map = mutableMapOf<String, Image>()
map.put("a") = 999
map.put("b") = 555
map.put("c") = 333
map.toSortedMap.... Not sure of the rest
```

When sorted, the items should be arranged as:
c, b, a

Not sure how to implement the sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This works. It won't return a map but a list of mapped items instead. For my sample, it returns:

`List<MutableMap.MutableEntry<String, Int>`

and to get this, you call:

`map.entries.sortedWith(compareByDescending({ it.value }))`

If the values refer to objects instead of basic types (Int, Boolean, etc), the objects are not copied but only a reference to them are placed in the returned list. That means that the object will exist in both the returned list and the original map. To destroy the object, it has to be removed from both the list and the map.